# Failed to get Firebase project xxxxxx. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I have two projects in Flutter (A, B), in project A I make the normal connection to Firebase and everything works fine, it brings data, sends data, updates and deletes data. since that project is from my personal google account, but when I use project B, which is not personal, it is from an external account, it does not let me bring data, it does not let me do anything and I get console.

`[2023-02-01T03:57:29.360Z]  @firebase/firestore:`

On the other hand when I do a firebase deploy I have the following error in my project B,

`Failed to get Firebase project xxxxxx. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it`

If anyone knows how I could verify the permissions on that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your account has access to the Firebase project by heading to this link `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{PROJECT-ID}/settings/iam` - just replace `{PROJECT-ID}` with the actual project ID of the Firebase project.

Once you've verified that you have the [needed permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview), check if you're logged-in on Firebase CLI with the correct account. If you're already logged in, running `firebase login` should display the currently logged-in user. Otherwise, it'll prompt you to login to an account.

If you have other issues with the Firebase project, it's best to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have permission from project owner

Try this :

```
firebase logout

firebase login
```

Login with your email that content your Firebase project

```
firebase use --add
```

Choose the name of your project

Now type: `firebase deploy`

---

Also this might help : `firebase login --reauth`